# To continue to add Object in Loop even when SaveChanges of Entity Framework give error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have entity object created outside a loop.

In the loop a object of model is created and saved, now in between if any object fails to get saved due to truncation error then EF starts giving error on every object. I think it has referenced the object in memory.

Code is something like this

```
 Entity dbEntity = new Entity();
 foreach(obj in list)
 {
   try
    {
     //some changes in object
     dbEntity.AddObject(obj);
     dbEntity.SaveChanges(); //at this point error comes
     obj=null;  
    }
    catch(ex as exception)
    {

    }
 }
```

so say suppose loop runs for first time object saved everything fine
when second object comes it has some text which is more than the field length
it gives error
now third time obj has less text but when `SaveChanges` take place it give the same error the truncation of text 
so if 50 objects are in list then only 1 st object is getting saved and if error is coming at 2nd object then rest all are giving error.

Comment: Maybe that's an indication something has gone horribly wrong and you should stop doing what you are doing. Generally, exceptions tend to mean that sort of thing. Swallowing any exception and trying to continue merrily along is generally not encouraged.

Comment: Ya I agree but their is need to do it, i want rest objects to get saved

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Deepesh that swallowing the exception isn't the way to go. The reason it's giving you the error though it because `dbEntity` internally has two lists. One that is 'in memory' and holds your changes and one that is actually persisted. When you add an item that throws an error, it prevents *anything currently in memory* from being added. In this case you add item 1, try to save and it works. You add item 2 and save and it fails. You add item 3 and now item 2 **and** item 3 try to be saved, 2 fails again and items 2 **and** 3 are not saved. Same for subsequent runs through the loop. If something fails, perhaps delete it from the dbEnttity collection before trying to save the next item.

Comment: in Catch I am using dbEntity.DeleteObject(obj);

Answer (score 0):

It may be acceptable to instantiate a new context in the catch block.

```
var context = new Context();
foreach (var obj in list)
{
    // do some stuff
    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do some logging operation
        context.Dispose();
        context = new Context();
    }
}
context.Dispose();
```